# AudioRecord Input Gain

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

I'm using AudioRecord to record an input from a 4-conductor audio jack. The problem is that the input is too loud and causes the signal to clip. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way that I could adjust the gain in software as I am recording it, so that no clipping occurs. I cannot use AutomaticGainControl because the signal dynamics are important for my purposes.

Thanks!